# Can we have a special checkbox or something for purposely self-answered questions?

Tags: support, self-answer, instant-self-answer

As stated [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250204/can-you-answer-your-own-questions-on-stack-overflow), one can pose a question with the purpose of answering it oneself.  Perhaps this is a tricky situation that you encountered in your own coding and fixed **and** the material does not already exist on SO.

Can there be a shortcut mechanism for this, especially with the fastest gun in the west style answering we have?  I am thinking that one should be able to ask, answer and accept in a single submit if that is one's purpose.

I think actually it is a courtesy to others because it lets these fast answerers know that they may find it better to get their reputation on another question.  The question and answer can still be downvoted into oblivion if neither meets the quality standards of the site.

**EDIT**

Maybe this would be a you need so much rep function if we are worried about spam piling up on our site.

Comment: Can't you just draw up the question and answer beforehand?

Comment: Status completed: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132886/what-is-this-answer-your-own-question-jazz Well, except for the accept, but we wouldn't want to discourage other answers from coming in anyway.

Comment: @Bart Thanks.  I would mark this as a duplicate (of a question on meta), but it says the question must be on MSO.  So perhaps it is better if I just delete it?

Comment: I answered it @demongolem. Its title doesn't make it easy to find on MSE anyway, and it doesn't do harm to have it here. This is bound to come up again at some point.

Comment: @demongolem don't just blindly delete your own duplicates, because doing that too often **makes the question-ban algorithm hunt you down and silence you. Forever...** `>:D`

Comment: Not really here on this meta @Cupcake, afaik.

Answer (score 22):

That feature already exists, as shown [in this post on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132886/what-is-this-answer-your-own-question-jazz). When asking your question you can immediately answer it. Just click on the "Answer your own question" checkbox, and write your answer.

> [image]

The only thing it won't allow you to do is immediately accept your answer. But then again, perhaps the community has some additional valuable input. Or who knows, they might even be smarter than you are and come up with something far more brilliant. ;)

Comment: Smarter than me? Pffff... :P