# What to do when I answer my own poor, unanswered questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, unanswered-questions, self-answer

[A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23351367/simpleform-check-existing-has-many-records) [number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23408844/simple-form-f-association-on-subset-of-model-association) of my [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24038984/how-to-change-label-name-attribute-in-simple-fields-for/24065064#24065064) were fairly specific.  They received no votes or answers, so perhaps they were too specific.  I eventually solve my problems and answer my questions, selecting that answer so that there is a Q&A, per the goal of SO.

However, I later return to the questions and, with more knowledge of the domain, feel like the questions don't actually contribute to the knowledge base that is SO.  Deleting them, now that they are answered, offers up warnings about it being a bad idea and losing my asking privileges.

What is the "right" way to handle these situations?  Find better answers and flag to close as dupes?  Leave them?  Delete them despite the warnings?

Comment: Let the communtiy decide if they're not a good fit. You may feel they're not good, but others might. Similarly, others may find they're not great and vote to close / delete / downvote etc.

Comment: What about in light of [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253050/2483138)?  Does this not constitute breaking the guideline "don't self-answer really basic questions"?

Comment: Just flag that question to moderator saying that the question seems to be of low quality or something similar. You may get that question deleted upon getting 50 similar flags from others. It's just a way of closing a question.

Comment: @Ganesh He can delete the question himself right now if he wanted to.  He's just asking if he should.  Because of that, a mod is just going to dismiss the flag as something you could do yourself.

Comment: @Servy Are the penalties associated with deleting the question myself present in the mod-deleted case too?  Would I lose asking permissions that way?

Comment: @ABMagil Yes, and note that deleting wouldn't *necessarily* mean that you couldn't ask immediately, but it counts against you in the algorithm to determine if you should be banned.  Deleting these posts may or may not push you beyond the threshold for being banned, we can't really know.

Comment: @ABMagil Do you intend on answering this question?

Comment: I'm wondering why [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23351367/simpleform-check-existing-has-many-records) has been questionned ***and*** answered in less than a minute.

Comment: @zessx When you ask a question, there is a checkbox that lets you write an answer too at the same time, and post them together. He probably used that.

Comment: I'd also recommend explaining *why* your answers work where you can, not just how you solved them.

Comment: @zessx When I figure something out that's worthy of a question/answer but hasn't been even asked yet, I often post the question and the answer simultaneously. There's an option to do just that when asking a question - it's there for a good reason :)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Absolutely answer them, and keep them open.  People coming along in the future may have the same problem.  I know I've found Q/A pairs that had CV's on them as 'too localized' and yet they still helped.

I also find I learn a lot from answering my old questions.  It's a lot of fun, and I can see how far I've come.  ([This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10557809/bug-in-incrementing-program/23838687#23838687) is my favorite).

If it ends up getting a lot of downvotes, you may want to delete it.  Otherwise, the community can close if they feel it necessary.

Comment: Nice sass on the JSFiddle.  Got you good, past self!

Comment: Agreed. Please answer your own questions to help the community **and yourself in the future.** I'm sure that most of us have had the same problem several times and found our own questions from months or years before. I know I have... and I have always rewarded myself with a beer for taking the time to come back and answer them (this was even before SO existed).

Comment: @stackular Don't we all love the moment when we find an excellent SO answer that solves our problem - that we wrote six months ago.

Comment: @SomeKittensUx2666 not as much as we hate googling symptoms, finding a perfect-sounding question....only to discover that we wrote it ourselves for the problem we're still working on.

Answer (score 6):

This topic may clarify:

[Can you answer your own questions on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250204/can-you-answer-your-own-questions-on-stack-overflow)

But answering your own questions, which you spend time and effort in solving, just improves the knowledge.

Even if your question is too basic, you have to consider that, if you didnt get many downvotes (community decides what must go away) the question may help new users or so.

> The site is here so developers can share their knowledge. by: [codeMagic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1380752/codemagic)

Comment: Questions that are really basic, or, more correctly, questions to which the answers are already readily available *don't* help anyone else, because the information was already readily available.  So the question is whether or not these particular posts contain information that would be useful to others, and that isn't already easy to find.

Comment: Agreed, so the community can vote to close the topic. If time has passed, and there's a few upvotes to the question but missing the answer, go answer it.

Comment: The questions are *already* answered.  He's asking if he should delete them or leave them.