# The user asked a question and give the answer in 30 seconds. Maybe it should be marked as community post?

Tags: discussion, answers, asking-questions

I saw such questions many times - some user asked a good (well structured) question and at the same moment gives the good answer on his/her own post.  I don't know is it a good or not.

At the one side it looks like a cheating, but at the other side the author can help the community. I have an experience - I can share my knowledge, why not?

Maybe it is better to mark such questions\answers as community posts?

---

Update:

**The case**

Someone (*Billy the Kid*) have some experience in a tag with a low attendance. And he wants to share some trick with community.

*Billy the Kid*: Posts the question and posts the answer in 30 seconds (he is smart and fast).

*Stranger*: Open the post, compare the authors of question and answer and make a downvote. He just don't like cheaters.

The question: Who will be protect *Billy* (he is upset and confused because he made a good deal)? He is good guy and wants to make the world better. Where is a sheriff?

---

Update: 
My post is a try to offer something for solving similar issues. I saw the [Can you answer your own questions on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250204/876298) post and similar questions.

Comment: I don't understand the situation you are talking about.  Is this a Fastest-Gun issue?  Or a self-answer problem?

Comment: Self-answers like that are not just allowed, they're also encouraged and built-in to the system. (Did notice the "answer your question" checkbox when you ask a question?) So no, you don't have to mark those as community wiki. At the same time, from what I understand, you _cant_ mark a question ask community wiki- A mod has to. So you'd have to flag a mod for it, and unless you intend for a lot of people to be editing the posts to keep them up to date, it's really just not worth it.

Comment: @sphanley The answers on that post do not address what appears to be the core question here: Should the posts be made community wiki if this is done?

Comment: Since you're asserting that this is solving a problem, what is the problem to be solved, and why does this solve it?

Comment: @Servy Someone can use such methods for just increasing his/her score. The community can solve this collision

Comment: @AlexK Yes, people can increase their score by posting quality questions and quality answers that other people find useful.  That's by design; that's not a problem.  Preventing people from being rewarded for *beneficial behavior* would be the problem.

Comment: @AlexK that's fine.  Why shouldn't a person who spent time writing a __good__ Q&A pair get reputation for sharing knowledge?  Of course, it's hard to do well.  Heck, a lot of self-answers make the OP _lose_ reputation from downvotes.

Comment: @ryanyuyu `Heck, a lot of self-answers make the OP lose reputation from downvotes` - I know it. It was the main reason to write this post

Comment: @Servy It is looks like writing a guides. Is it a "SO-style"?

Comment: @AlexK Posting good questions and good answers is an SO style, yes.  It's not a guide, it's just a good question with a good answer, like any other question you'd see on SO.  If it's not a good question, or a good answer, then vote accordingly.

Comment: @Servy Ok. I don't understand why some people made downvotes for such good posts. It is not a problem for a popular tags, but for a some tags it is a problem, I think.

Comment: @AlexK If you think having good questions with good answers is a problem, then you're on the wrong site.  SE *exists* to create quality questions with quality answers.

Comment: @Servy You don't understand my comment. I mean that at some tags (with a low attendance) you can post great post and take the downvote(s) because someone don't like self-answers. And there is low chance to take supported upvotes (because the tag's audience is low)

Comment: @AlexK If someone feels that the post isn't a great post, they're free to downvote it.  Just because you feel that a post is a great post doesn't mean that everyone else is obligated to agree with you.

Comment: If someone comments that a self-answer is "cheating", then point them to the help center like I mentioned in my answer. Educate them, don't punish posters of good content because voters think they're doing things wrong. (And if the user didn't comment that this was the reason they downvoted, don't assume it is- There could be something else they find wrong with the post(s).)

Answer (score 16):

No, you don't have to make a question community wiki in order to ask and answer at the same time. All you have to do is click the checkbox labelled "Answer your own question" when you create the question.

In reality, [only answer authors can mark their post as a community wiki.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) You would have to flag your question and have a mod do so, and if you don't intend for the post to be edited and evolving to be kept up to date by many people... There's no point in it. If you just want to share your knowledge, there's no need for people to continuously edit the post.

Asking and answering your own question is encouraged, and if someone gets upset with you over it, [point them to the help center.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

As for gaining reputation for these posts (brought up in the comments), if the posts are *good, on-topic, and useful* why shouldn't the user get rep for it? If the posts are bad, expect them to be moderated the same as any other posts. We do not make quality exceptions for self-answers. If a user could post the same question without the answer and get rep, or post the same answer to the same question by a different user and get rep, why shouldn't they if they post both?

Comment: Some users can use this mechanism just for "farming" score

Comment: @AlexK So you're saying we shouldn't allow people to post non-CW answers to questions because they can get points for it if they post a good answer to a good question?  If that's your argument, then you're arguing that the entire rep system should be removed because people are "farming" score when they post good answers to good questions.

Comment: @AlexK - If someone gets upvotes for contributing a great question / answer pair, I have no problem with that. People still have to vote on the content. Likewise, if they contribute a bad question and answer they'll be penalized and can end up getting banned from posting. Of all the schemes I've seen for "farming" reputation, this one ranks near the bottom in terms of frequency and viability.

Comment: @BradLarson `Of all the schemes I've seen for "farming" reputation, this one ranks near the bottom in terms of frequency and viability` - It is a good news )

Answer (score 8):

A CW post is a post that is not written by one person, but is rather a collaboration of multiple people, and a post for which other users are actively encouraged to contribute their own content to.

The fact that someone is answering their own question does not mean that the answer is a collaborative work of many people, so no, it should not necessarily be marked as CW.  If someone happens to post an answer to their own question that also happens to be a collaborative work that others contributed significantly to, then they can choose to mark the post as CW.