# Does Answering your question increases points on SO?

Tags: support, answers, comments

So I work with WSO2 frameworks and there are not a lot of developers for it out there. I posted a question regarding it yesterday but did not get any kind of response. Now that I have figured it out on my own, will it help my reputation on SO to add it's answer as a comment?

Comment: As a comment? No, please [feel free to answer your own questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250204/1233251), as long as they're of good quality. In terms of reputation, you just don't receive 2 points for accepting it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering your own questions is something that's actually encouraged in contexts like yours. There's even [a badge you can get from answering your own questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/14/self-learner):

[image]

Besides this badge, you can get upvotes and downvotes for that answer, just like you can get them from any other answer or question. However, you won't get any perks from "accepting" your own answer (ticking the green check next to it), just like you can't upvote or downvote your own posts.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should answer your own question, but not as a comment.

According to [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), answering your own questions is encouraged:

> ### Can I answer my own question?
>
> Yes! Stack Exchange has always explicitly encouraged users to answer their own questions. If you have a question that you already know the answer to, and you would like to document that knowledge in public so that others (including yourself) can find it later, it's perfectly okay to ask and answer your own question on a Stack Exchange site.

From [Stackoverflow blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), by Jeff Atwood on July 1, 2011:

> It’s also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question, as long as you pretend you’re on Jeopardy! — phrase it in the form of a question.
>
> [image: jeopardy!]

Answer (score 0):

Writing your own answer and getting upvotes on it does give you reputation points as normal.

Marking your own answer as accepted however, does not give you any reputation gain.

A [blog post by Jeff Atwood](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) says:

> No reputation is earned. Normally, accepted answers confer +15 rep to the answerer and +2 to the owner. Owner accepted answers do not earn rep (or badges) for anyone.

Although you can now earn a badge since that blog post was made, the rules on reputation are the same.