# What did I done wrong in my Question

Tags: discussion, questions, deleted-questions

So in the end my Question got deleted ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8lPf.png)). I am not complaining I just want to know what i did wrong.

So let me explain what happend: I asked a question about what advantages Eto has in comparison to WPF (both .NET GUI frameworks). At first I had a little conversation with Broots Waymb, he tried to explain that the advantage is the cross platform nature of Eto (The conversation looks weird because some guys deleted their comments).

Than it began i got some downvotes and the question was put on hold because it was primarily opinion based. I didn't understood this because I asked for advantages and facts and not for opinions.

Then i began researching for myself and I found the answer. I added the answer below my question if someone has the same question and wants to get an answer to that question. But then they voted for deletion and the question got deleted. I have no idea why, maybe I broke a guideline or a rule. I hope there is somebody who can tell me what i did wrong. :)

[Link to the Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51751277/why-use-eto-instead-of-wpf)

Comment: Can you [edit] this question and provide a screenshot to your deleted question?

Comment: Ok i am working on it.

Comment: What you consider the advantages and disadvantages of an entire framework is *an opinion*.  It's not a fact.  That you formed an opinion and shared it doesn't mean that the question isn't opinion based.

Comment: I've added in a link to a screenshot.

Comment: Sounds like [Gorilla vs Shark](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/16/gorilla-vs-shark/) to me. Questions comparing two technologies aren't a good fit for this site.

Comment: On a sidenote, please don't edit an answer into a question. If you have an answer to your own question, please post it as an answer.

Comment: @Codeer While solid advice, you can't do that with a closed question.

Comment: It’s a bad idea to include an answer in your question. Questions should only be for questions. The right place to put answers is in the answers section. See [Can you answer your own questions on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250204/4642212).

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I know, but it was a general remark (not specific to this question).

Comment: I read the Gorilla vs Shark article and i think i understand what you mean but when i asked the question i just wanted to get the answer: Eto is cross platform and Wpf isn't. And maybe there are some people who would like to know the answer. That were my thoughts at that time

Comment: @Epig There are lots of places where people can go to share their opinions and have discussions about what they like and don't like about different platforms.  That place just isn't SO.

Comment: Things to read for better understanding: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/16/gorilla-vs-shark/.  The snark in the question is covered by: https://stackoverflow.com/conduct

Comment: @Epig so you read the post explaining this is off topic, then posted knowing it was off topic, and now you're surprised it got deleted?.... Not to be snarky, but I think It's easy to see that your need for an answer is not a good enough reason to bypass our rules, no?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all: Never edit the answer into your question.
If you've found an answer, *answer* the question. If the question is closed already, then you're out of luck. The closure is a sign that the question isn't a good fit for SO for one reason or another. Adding a answer to a question that doesn't belong on SO doesn't help future readers.

Your question, without the answer, is this:

> I just started to create desktop applications with C#. So I started experimenting with the **Eto GUI Framework**. But now i found out that there is already someting similar included in the .NET framework the **Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF)**. My question is are there any advantages that I would have if I would use the Eto Framework instead of the WPF framework.

That's rather broad and opinion based, which is why it got closed.

Comment: One last question: Why didn't this question got deleted? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6564795/wpf-vs-winforms-for-net-newbies Is there a difference or is it just the fact that he talks about more famous frameworks

Comment: @Epig: That question was asked more than 7 years ago. The rules have changed since then.

Comment: @Epig The question is now deleted.